# Getting Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, session

After dumping session, I get below result. Can anybody please tell me how I can get the value "product_id" and "info" that are in array(2);

```
array(3) { 
    ["DYN_outskin"]=> string(3) "ten" 
    ["DYN_inskin"]=> string(3) "one" 
    ["cart"]=> array(1) { 
        ["2000_facebook"]=> array(2) { 
            ["product_id"]=> string(13) "2000_facebook" 
            ["info"]=> string(7) "nur1952"
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: the path is array-->[2000_facebook] -->[cart] --> [product_id] then $arr[2000_facebook][cart][product_id]

Comment: @gd1: I got this result, it's print_r of session ======================= Array ( [DYN_outskin] => ten [DYN_inskin] => one [cart] => Array ( [2000_facebook] => Array ( [product_id] => 2000_facebook [info] => nur1952 ) [web_traffic] => Array ( [product_id] => web_traffic [info] => fbmuseum.com ) ) )

Comment: Voting to close as too localized as this unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: For the future I think you should use `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()` in my opinion it's simpler to read because it outputs the same way you write.

Comment: @Supremekhaoz Actually, `var_export` prints the same way you'd write.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Thanks! I didn't know about this function but print_r() is closer than var_dump anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$array['cart']['2000_facebook']['product_id'];
$array['cart']['2000_facebook']['info'];
```

Comment: Can you help me on this? It's for showing stored session data in foreach loop ==============================   
   <?php
   // adding item to cart
   $_SESSION['cart'][$git_product_id] = array('product_id' => $git_product_id, 'info' => $git_required);
   ?>
   
   <?php
   // showing session value
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product => $key ) : ?>
          // showing here product_id and info
    <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: sure I can help,  but please paste your code on urloment.com or pastebin.com.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SESSION["cart"]["2000_facebook"]["product_id"] ;

$_SESSION["cart"]["2000_facebook"]["info"] ;
```

iterate over cart:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $product){
  echo "Product info : {$product['info']} | Product ID : {$product['product_id']} <br/>" ;
}
```

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!! You have saved my another 24 hours. Thanks thanks!

Comment: No probs :) Accept though, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to display the array in a way that clearly displays the array structure, like so:

```
array(3) { 
  ["DYN_outskin"]=> string(3) "ten" 
  ["DYN_inskin"]=> string(3) "one" 
  ["cart"]=> array(1) { 
    ["2000_facebook"]=> array(2) { 
      ["product_id"]=> string(13) "2000_facebook" 
      ["info"]=> string(7) "nur1952" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Now, its clear how you can access the needed elements:

```
$array["cart"]["2000_facebook"]["product_id"]
$array["cart"]["2000_facebook"]["info"]
```